# Time value in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format

Tags: java, hibernate, datetime

Using hibernate for fetching the values from DB.

DB has below data for timevalue as datetime column(2016-04-11 23:54:11)

Hibernate has below data

```
<property name="timevalue" type="timestamp">
    <column name="timevalue" length="100" />
</property>
```

I have declared as below data

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private java.util.Date timevalue;
```

But when I tried fetching the data it is returned as `timevalue`:

> 1460399054000

But I need the timevalue as `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`

What should I do now for fixing it?

Comment: How are you printing or viewing `timevalue`?

Comment: GET http://localhost:8080/test/rest/question via REST                                  {
       "id": 2,
       "questions": "What is your name",
       "noans": 1,
       "username": "Harshitha 1",
       "timevalue": 1460399054000
   },

Comment: Use SimpleDateFormat as @Φxoce-웃-Пepeúpa suggests below or something similar like JodaTime. The `1460399054000` output is the default format in your environment, you need to format it explicitly for the format your API is exposing or for display to a user.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you get the data as a long then you can do:

```
long timeStamp = 1460399054000L; // what you wot from web service/DB
String format = "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:SS";
Date date = new Date(timeStamp);
String dateFormat =  new SimpleDateFormat(format).format(date);
System.out.println(dateFormat);
```

this will print

> 2016-04-102 20:04:00

Comment: Where should i implement this?I thought Hibernate will take care, please correct me

Comment: This is the method i am using

Comment: public List<Questions> readAll() {
  Session session = HibernateUtil.currentSession();
  List<Questions> results = session.createQuery("from Questions").list();
  // results.
  session.close();
  return results;
 }

Comment: No, don't use that format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`... `MM` is always the month, even if you sandwich it between the hours and the seconds. And `DD` is the day-of-the-year which is why you get 102. And `YYYY` is the week-year, which could be weird in the first few days of January or last few days of December. And `SS` is milliseconds, not seconds. Try `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with Joda Library

```
    long geTime= your value;
    GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("US/Central"));
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(geTime);
    DateTime jodaTime = new DateTime(geTime, 
    DateTimeZone.forTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("US/Central")));
    DateTimeFormatter parser1 = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    System.out.println("Get Time : "+parser1.print(jodaTime));
```